# Query that searches between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, jpql

Hi guys i have a search query that should display all the results between a set date range

the query :

```
public List<Appointment> appointmentRangeSearch(Date startdatetime, Date endDate) {
    Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM Appointment U WHERE u.startDatetime BETWEEN : date1 AND : date2 ");
    q.setParameter("date1", startdatetime, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
    q.setParameter("date2", endDate, TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);
    return q.getResultList();
}
```

it is returning the errror :

```
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-0] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.JPQLException
Exception Description: Syntax error parsing [SELECT u FROM Appointment U WHERE u.startDatetime BETWEEN : date1 AND : date2 ]. 
[34, 77] The expression is not a valid conditional expression.
```

the data in the table is stored :

```
2013-12-15 00:00:00.0
```

how can i complete this search ?

thanks guys

Comment: Try removing the space between `:` and `date1` from `: date1`

Comment: thank you !! i love it when it is something simple like that !

Answer (score 1):

Remove the space between `:` and `date1` from `: date1`. So your query should be like this:

```
SELECT u FROM Appointment U WHERE u.startDatetime BETWEEN :date1 AND :date2
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax error has been solved but you might have a logic problem not related to your question.  If your datatype is datetime, and the data includes a time portion, then this:

```
where myField between '2013-12-01' and '2013-12-05'
```

will not pick up records with values like 2013-12-05 01:00

The solution is to do this

```
where myField >= '2013-12-01'
and myField < '2013-12-06' -- note that this is one day later
```